# Why wont this print out a shuffled list?

Tags: python

Im trying to print out a list of user input after its been shuffled. Instead of printing the list it prints "none". What am I doing wrong?

```
import random 

x = raw_input("Write one word: ")
word1 = x
y = raw_input("Write another word: ")
word2 = y
z = raw_input("Write one more word: ")
word3 = z

all_words = [word1, word2, word3] 
random_words = random.shuffle(all_words)

print random_words
```

Comment: Please check the Python documentation. From the documentation: "Shuffle the sequence x in place.". That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.shuffle` mutates the input list and returns `None`.  If you `print all_words`, you'll see a shuffled list.

Comment: Thanks for marking my question as a duplicate now I cant ask anymore questions. What a great learning environment SO is! So welcoming!!!